# Rspec - stub module method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking

How can I stub a method within a module:

```
module SomeModule
    def method_one
        # do stuff
        something = method_two(some_arg)
        # so more stuff
    end

    def method_two(arg)
        # do stuff
    end
end
```

I can test `method_two` in isolation fine.

I would like to test `method_one` in isolation too by stubbing the return value of `method_two`:

```
shared_examples_for SomeModule do
    it 'does something exciting' do
        # neither of the below work
        # SomeModule.should_receive(:method_two).and_return('MANUAL')
        # SomeModule.stub(:method_two).and_return('MANUAL')

        # expect(described_class.new.method_one).to eq(some_value)
    end
end

describe SomeController do
    include_examples SomeModule
end
```

The specs in `SomeModule` that are included in `SomeController` fail because `method_two` throws an exception (it tries to do a db lookup that has not been seeded).

How can I stub `method_two` when it is called within `method_one`?

Comment: what do you expect from this module? to be a mixin or to call method from it at class level like: `SomeModule.foo` ?

Comment: Take heart, George. Downvotes on questions are a generally bad idea, in my opinion, but the good news is that inappropriate ones frequently stimulate countervailing upvotes, with a net rep win for you and no net vote impact.

Comment: In addition to @apneadving's question, it's not clear what the relationship of the module to the controller in the code you're trying to test. Also, it's not clear to me what passing a class name to `shared_examples_for` does, as I've only seen a string used as an argument in the documentation as a way to invoke it.

Comment: In any event, if your controller mixes in that module, you need to stub the controller instance methods, not the module class method as you've tried to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
shared_examples_for SomeModule do
  let(:instance) { described_class.new }

  it 'does something exciting' do
    instance.should_receive(:method_two).and_return('MANUAL')
    expect(instance.method_one).to eq(some_value)
  end
end

describe SomeController do
  include_examples SomeModule
end
```

Comment: Please try to include some explanation on what's going on and your reasoning behind this.

Answer (score 5):

```
allow_any_instance_of(M).to receive(:foo).and_return(:bar)
```

[Is there a way to stub a method of an included module with Rspec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408717/is-there-a-way-to-stub-a-method-of-an-included-module-with-rspec)

This approach works for me