# Is there a way to stub a method of an included module with Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mixins, stubbing

I have a module that is included in another module, and they both implement the same method.
I would like to stub the method of the included module, something like this:

```
module M
  def foo
    :M
  end
end

module A
  class << self
    include M

    def foo
      super
    end
  end
end

describe "trying to stub the included method" do
  before { allow(M).to receive(:foo).and_return(:bar) }

  it "should be stubbed when calling M" do
    expect(M.foo).to eq :bar
  end

  it "should be stubbed when calling A" do
    expect(A.foo).to eq :bar
  end
end
```

The first test is passing, but the second one outputs:

```
Failure/Error: expect(A.foo).to eq :bar

   expected: :bar
        got: :M
```

Why isn't the stub working in this case?
Is there a different way to achieve this?

Thanks!

-------------------------------------UPDATE----------------------------------

Thanks! using allow_any_instance_of(M) solved this one.
My next question is - what happens if I use prepend and not include? see the following code:

```
module M
  def foo
    super
  end
end

module A
  class << self
    prepend M

    def foo
      :A
    end
  end
end

describe "trying to stub the included method" do
  before { allow_any_instance_of(M).to receive(:foo).and_return(:bar) }

  it "should be stubbed when calling A" do
    expect(A.foo).to eq :bar
  end
end
```

This time, using allow_any_instance_of(M) results in an infinite loop. why is that?

Answer (score 40):

Note you cannot directly call `M.foo`! Your code only seems to work because you mocked `M.foo` to return `:bar`.

When you open `A` metaclass (`class << self`) to include `M`, you have to mock any instance of `M`, that is adding to your `before` block:

`allow_any_instance_of(M).to receive(:foo).and_return(:bar)`

```
module M
  def foo
    :M
  end
end

module A
  class << self
    include M

    def foo
      super
    end
  end
end

describe "trying to stub the included method" do
  before do
    allow(M).to receive(:foo).and_return(:bar)
    allow_any_instance_of(M).to receive(:foo).and_return(:bar)
  end


  it "should be stubbed when calling M" do
    expect(M.foo).to eq :bar
  end

  it "should be stubbed when calling A" do
    expect(A.foo).to eq :bar
  end
end
```

Comment: This works.  Apparently, unlike `allow`, `allow_any_instance_of` doesn't require the method to be defined on the object.

Comment: i think this just helped me solve 5+ hours worth of banging my head on the table. thanks!

Comment: Cf., `expect_any_instance_of`... this put me on the right track